# MySQL doesn't update text field with textarea

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I want to update a text field in my mysql database but it doesn't change when I run the query. I've tried stripping special characters but it still doesn't work.

UPDATE: It returns the following error: It gives the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'datatext='LET OP! Aantal Mate' at line 1

Here is the data:

The HTML

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="nr" value="1">
<textarea rows="20" cols="50" name="text"></textarea>
</form>
```

The PHP

```
$change_text = $_POST['text'];
$change_nr = $_POST['nr'];
if ((!empty($change_text))&&(!empty($change_nr)))
{
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET datatext='$change_text' WHERE datanr='$change_nr'");
}
```

Structure MySQL (tablename = table)

```
datanr = int(6)
order = text utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: Does it throw an error. You tried to strip special characters - is it working when posting text without special characters?

Comment: Run this and tell us what the error is: mysql_query("UPDATE table SET datatext='$change_text' WHERE datanr='$change_nr'") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: What's the name of the col, in your query you use **datatext**, but your structure shows **order**

Comment: obligatory "Lil' Johny Tables" reference for not escaping your values http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: It gives the following error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'datatext='LET OP! Aantal Mate' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text area is not to blame. your sql references a column name that your table doesn't seem to have.

Your schema has `datanr` and `order` while the update query has `datanr` and `datatext`.

Some more tips:

1. don't use mysql keywords as column or table names or at least escape them with `backticks` if you must.
2. always validate/sanitise your user input
3. don't use `mysql` but use [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli), [pdo](http://php.net/pdo) or better yet, a good [data access layer](https://www.google.nl/search?q=php%20data%20access%20layer&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: Sorry, the field name is the same. My mistake :s

Comment: I've finally solved it and it was a small stupid thing. I called a MySQL column 'order'... And since that is a query statement it returned an error. Thanks for all the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

try to check with key exists instead empty

```
    if (array_key_exists('nr', $_POST)) {
        $change_text = $_POST['text'];
        $change_nr = $_POST['nr'];
        mysql_query("UPDATE table SET datatext='$change_text' WHERE datanr='$change_nr'");
    }
```

Comment: OP's problem is `MySQL doesnt update text field with textarea`

Comment: The problem is not in the if statement because it will echo a message. It also runs the query when I remove the datatext='$change_text' part so it has something to do with writing the data in into the database text field.

Answer (score 0):

Debug your code

```
var_dump($_POST);

$change_text = $_POST['text'];
$change_nr = $_POST['nr'];

if ((!empty($change_text))&&(!empty($change_nr)))
{
    $sqlString = "UPDATE table SET datatext='$change_text' WHERE datanr='$change_nr'";
    var_dump($sqlString);
    mysql_query($sqlString) or die(mysql_errno() . " " . mysql_error()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form lacks <input type="submit" />. Without submit button, form (and data) cannot be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Haha! I know the problem! It is the query. You must use those special quotes around column names. Like this: mysql_query("UPDATE table SET `datatext`='$change_text' WHERE datanr='$change_nr'");

Notice ` quotes aound datatext. Now your script should work. If it doesn't, I will shut down my pc and go to bed immediatelly lol

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET datatext='".$change_text."' WHERE datanr=".$change_nr);
```